# Identity-layout-renderer is not rendering anything for .NET Core console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core, nlog

I have a .NET Core Console application.

like this:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm running on Windows 10 with VS 2019.

I cannot get the below layout renderer to log anything.

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Identity-layout-renderer

```
${identity:authType=Boolean:separator=String:name=Boolean
          :isAuthenticated=Boolean}
```

My nlog.config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XSD manual extracted from package NLog.Schema: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Schema-->
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="NLog NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogFile="MyApp.NLog.INTERNAL.log"
      internalLogLevel="Info" >

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- write logs to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="target1" fileName="MyApp.NLog.${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${date}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|***|${identity:authType=true:separator=/:name=true:isAuthenticated=true}|****|${message} ${exception:format=toString,Data}|${all-event-properties}" />

  </targets>



  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="target1" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

example log:  :(

```
2020/02/19 12:03:40.617|INFO|MyCompany.MyObject|***||****|HeyYouThere |
```

Nothing between ***||**** :(

and nlog internal log output (MyApp.NLog.INTERNAL.log) (no errors)

```
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3612 Info Auto loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3734 Info Loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3847 Info NLog.Extensions.Logging, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 1.6.1.1203. Product version: 1.6.1.
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3847 Info Auto loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.Extensions.Logging.dll succeeded!
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3847 Info Auto loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.WindowsIdentity.dll
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3847 Info Loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.WindowsIdentity.dll
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3938 Info NLog.WindowsIdentity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5120e14c03d0593c. File version: 4.6.8.10751. Product version: 4.6.8.
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3938 Info Auto loading assembly file: c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\NLog.WindowsIdentity.dll succeeded!
2020-02-19 12:03:38.3938 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2020-02-19 12:03:38.4652 Info Adding target FileTarget(Name=target1)
2020-02-19 12:03:38.5111 Info Found 39 configuration items
2020-02-19 12:03:38.5614 Info Configuration file change detected! Reloading in 1000ms...
2020-02-19 12:03:38.5614 Info Configuration file change detected! Reloading in 1000ms...
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5688 Info Reloading configuration...
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5688 Info Configuring from an XML element in c:\myfolder1\myfolder2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\nlog.config...
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5688 Info Message Template Auto Format enabled
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5688 Info Adding target FileTarget(Name=target1)
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5688 Info Closing old configuration.
2020-02-19 12:03:39.5987 Info Found 39 configuration items
```

Nuget packages

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NLog" Version="4.6.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.Extensions.Logging" Version="1.6.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="NLog.WindowsIdentity" Version="4.6.8" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

As far as I can see, it looks like I have the nuget package

```
.nuget\packages\nlog\4.6.8\lib\netstandard2.0\NLog.dll
namespace NLog.LayoutRenderers
{
    [LayoutRenderer("identity")]
    public class IdentityLayoutRenderer : LayoutRenderer
```

Comment: What happens if you use `${environment-user}` ? See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Environment-User-Layout-Renderer

Comment: with environment user, I do get what is in my environment variables for the "USERNAME" value.  But your link was helpful.  "On Windows the Environment.UserName property wraps a call to the Windows GetUserName function. On Unix platforms the UserName property wraps a call to the getpwuid_r function."  Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

From the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29151) (thanks @granadaCoder)

> NET Core has different default. The default principal policy in .NET Core is no principal.
>
> If you would like to keep .NET Framework behavior, call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.UnauthenticatedPrincipal)` in the Main method of your app.

Comment: I cannot accept my answer as "the answer" until 2 days (SOF policy).  But I upvoted this.. since you did find the magic paragraph in the link!

Comment: Added also to https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Identity-layout-renderer

Comment: Super plus for updating the documentation for future readers everywhere.....#goldStar

Answer (score 0):

So the code in

https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/LayoutRenderers/IdentityLayoutRenderer.cs

here is the primary piece of code:

```
    private static IIdentity GetValue()
    {
        var currentPrincipal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        return currentPrincipal?.Identity;
    }
```

When I run the below (slightly edited, just to see what it does)

```
        var currentPrincipal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        var ident = currentPrincipal?.Identity;
```

ident is null.

So that's why I get nothing in the log file.............the code resolves to null.

## goFigure

So after a little homework.

The Thread.CurrentPrincipal is purposely empty.

In ASP.NET CORE, one would do something like this (typical internet answer I found)

You basically take advantage of the complete Dependency Injection overhaul.......and use that.

And with the DI approach, do you NOT rely on System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal; "being around".  (Keep reading for a work-around to this)

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
    services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(
        provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);

    // ...
}
```

With DotNet.Core (console app)... you probably have to add one

pseudo code below

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ClaimsPrincipal myprinc = new ClaimsPrincipal(  /* you'll need a ClaimsIdentity and some claims here probably */ );

    //or
    GenericPrincipal myprinc = new GenericPrincipal ( /* you'll need GenericIdentity and some roles here probably */ );


    services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(
        provider => myprinc);

    // ...
}
```

So this was not an NLog issue.  This was how DotNetCore handles System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal; differently.

Here is a good read:

https://davidpine.net/blog/principal-architecture-changes/

Now for the workaround:

I have verified that if I do this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(System.Security.Principal.PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
    
var currentPrincipal = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
var ident = currentPrincipal?.Identity;
```

I get what I (used to) expect!

and the log message.

```
2020/02/19 12:03:40.617|INFO|MyCompany.MyObject|***|MyDomain\MyUserName|****|HeyYouThere |
```

I need to run on my linux box to see what happens (if I find time).. Maybe a "does not exist in the current context" exception ??

Please do not use the "AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy" blindly.
Read the davidpine article about why System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal; is oldSchool.  And DI is probably the better approach going forward.

Also (if you choose to use) :

Here is the enum:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.principalpolicy?view=netcore-3.1

> Fields
>
> NoPrincipal   1    No principal or identity objects should be
> created.
>
> UnauthenticatedPrincipal  0    Principal and identity objects for the
> unauthenticated entity should be created. An unauthenticated entity
> has Name set to the empty string ("") and IsAuthenticated set to
> false.
>
> WindowsPrincipal  2    Principal and identity objects that reflect the
> operating system token associated with the current execution thread
> should be created, and the associated operating system groups should
> be mapped into roles.

You should consider each of the values.  And you should consider the "what happens on linux" issue, if you need that.

Will this happen?

> "'Windows Principal functionality is not supported on this platform.'"

Comment: This might be the issue : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29151

Comment: From your link: ".NET Core has different default. The default principal policy in .NET Core is no principal.

If you would like to keep .NET Framework behavior, call `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.UnauthenticatedPrincipal)` in the Main method of your app."

Comment: Yes, that is totally what is learning-curve and different with core.  I'll by pass the SetPrincipalPolicy .. but will post some extra in this answer.  thanks for the call out.

Comment: I posted this as separate answer, but maybe you should change your answer and I could remove mine.